# Reduce() to state object Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux

I'm having a trouble accessing redux state with `Array.prototype.reduce()` function inside a `.ts` file.

Here is the simplified example:

```
const state = store.getState();
const path: string = ["orders", "delay"].reduce(
   (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator[currentValue], state) 

// it correlates to: const path = state.orders.delay 

// accumulator - string
// currentValue - string
// state - result of combineReducers, middleware, and devtools
```

In the end of the reduce() I'll get a "string", but now I'm getting an error because state is not a "string" type.

How do I type this correctly?

Comment: That's going to be very awkward to type for arbitrary depth. I would recommend using recursion.

Comment: Hey Aluan, can you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

This is very difficult (by which I mean very manual) in TypeScript:

```js
// Unfortunately you will need to write a lot of manual function overloads
function getValue<S, P1 extends keyof S>(state: S, path: [P1]): S[P1];
function getValue<S, P1 extends keyof S, P2 extends keyof S[P1]>(state: S, path: [P1, P2]): S[P1][P2];
function getValue<S, P1 extends keyof S, P2 extends keyof S[P1], P3 extends keyof S[P1][P2]>(
  state: S,
  path: [P1, P2, P3],
): S[P1][P2][P3];
function getValue<S>(state: S, path: (keyof S)[]) {
  // You can also use your reduce solution, this is faster since it does not involve a function call
  let current: any = state;
  for (let i = 0; i < path.length; i++) current = current[path[i]];

  return current;
}
```

Basically you are declaring as many function overloads as there are levels in your state. What you get in return is pretty sweet though, check out this [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=45&ssc=61&pln=35&pc=1#code/PTAEFUDsDMHsCcAuBXSBDRBTANgT1LrMqAO4CW22okmmAJqIrKfGVqGqNrIqLNKAC2aSMjRVoqAMaIysSHwBumeNzR0AzgChJkGXIUBzTIgBq45JgA8AZQA0oAAoBGUJgAeWSJtABrTIQCNgB8ABQaiBiYAFyg9qAADhgAFrEA2i4AugCUsTYZzpkA3DrSsvKgxmYW1vEubp6Y3hp%20AfxxDo4ATA1ePv6BcQWZYRFReQ5JiKmgBZ1dOXnDGQsluvoVVebYlradrh59LQPtdT2HTf1tQcOdAMy9l8fXQ1krI6FaoKBjWBNfiRS6Rc83umTsWlyr0K7wyd2KpT05SMJm2uxC4Uifw6gOmsVCJyC2TSOVAAG8ASBQABNIigKQiDjYDTMZAaTAEIjwUDwejIKQclk7ZEOaZkFri0DQNARFQ-Mh6DlsUB0WCYFqQHigBWKWDYZQcKVlAz08TYAHYEz05DwXmQRCxET4AC8PyxmBK3zg3NClt4ZFAroADEVtaArLjkgA6S2QQzTUNkADUSey1ttTV4rqkNrtiDSU2SaTImQRAN5KHgChzGftJQAvlotFSAHIAeQA6qAADIAUQAKgByGygfsAJWpoAAkv3QG3wP2m1SbLBBByPGhBAlLW6oloFVh4NKBXP4HQVBobO7yQDvufsGhcLFRIIAEYqBtNg8qY8cmzJWAEivKIb2%20b4EHPeANFiNszwvYCsE-fd7R-NATwQjkKTAn4AISPJcIwpCqQAQW8LgTEHFpzykB9eUNRQ0FYNBXx3X4OXaRBcASP93S0ajaI5KR5AiXdsUIpcwA7BBfA0ABCeTZK0ITIBEjQCPdfDAIwwNKlRGpMSiBw0ko3DBxyEplJEiD4I009IMva9XS2fS2KMkzAMHBxB2sqCzOyCzhN4e9H2fZA3zlJy9J2TADKwNy1I8ryfI0TzQEHYLcD8kpmzAftknVQUAOQbAGE1XgSGkiTQA7eB5EMRguPYgQMqUwKVRwELqDC99uUi6potizB4tMpK4N88yqpqurI1alTeGS0Lwt63T%20ssQbhsStKAFkpxsftiIAaV7LKgA) with the code and examples!

Comment: Ján, I can not know how many items in the array, it could be 1 or 100 (just an example)

Comment: I can simply add `any` `const state: any = store.getState()`, and it will dirty-fix it, but I rather do not, if any reasonable type-checking option is available.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, my solution only addressed the return type of the whole thing and type checked the path. I think i have a good solution in mind, let me get back to my laptop and try something. It will require TypeScript 4.0 though, is that something you can live with?

Comment: I can update it to the latest, but as I can see the latest stable 3.9.5...

Comment: If it helps, here is the [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62812472/type-nested-property-state-in-array-reduce-redux-typescript)

Comment: Oh yes I see now that 4.0 is not out yet, it has this new feature called variadic tuple types that is required for a clean solution https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39094

Comment: I'll go with 4.0 if you illustrate your idea